# How to prevent label truncation in a Cognos BI Pie Chart

Tags: pie-chart, cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-10

I'm trying to create a pie chart in Cognos BI that shows complete labels. I can't figure out how to do this. I have included an image that shows how the current report truncates the labels and places three dots (...) at the end of each label. I have a couple questions:

1. Can what I want to do be accomplished?
2. Why does every label end with "..." and can they be eliminated?

**Update:** I'm running Cognos BI 10.1.1

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you you can absolutely prevent it.  But you can make the text longer.  In your chart, select the label.  In the properties, under general, you'll see `Text Truncation`.  Click the ellipse by it. It's probably set to the default of `automatic`.  Change it to `manual`, and you can put in whatever number of characters you want it to show.

Keep in mind that this can end up giving you some kind of funky looking charts.  The hover will show the full value of the column if you need to be able to see it on demand.

Comment: What version of Cognos are you running? I'm on 10.1.1 and I do not see "Text Truncation" under general.

Comment: Do you have `Use legacy chart authoring` selected?  (Under Tools/Options, on the advanced tab)

Comment: "Use legacy chart authoring" was checked. I unchecked it and I still don't see an option called "Text Truncation". I've tried so many different things I don't remember anymore what stuff looked like. At one point I do remember having the labels display all the text but the size of the pie was very small. This is very frustrating.